# Java extract field delimited substring using regex

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, syslog, flume

How do I extract programname from a syslog message using regex? I have a Java stream processing module that accepts regexs to process syslog messages.

The log line could be:

```
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd[6359]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd:3322 Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd/6359 Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname SSHD[1133] Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname SSH.D[6359]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
```

The string extraction process should be: take the third sub-string delimited by space, and extract sub-string that ends in `[`, `:`, `/` or space

So in the first four log samples, the extracted string would be `sshd`, the fifth `SSHD` and sixth `SSH.D`. Is this possible with a regex?

Edit:

What I tried is `((?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.-]+))` and it seems to work but to be honest, I modified an example regex and used an online tool to tweak it till it fit my use case but I am not sure exactly how it worked.

Comment: Yep. It's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: What I tried is "((?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.-]+))" and it seems to work but to be honest, I modified an example regex and used an online tool to tweak it till it fit my use case but I am not sure exactly how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Double `split` should do the job:

```
String token = data.split(" +")[2].split("[\\[:/]")[0];
```

Comment: I am passing regex in flume config to the regex interceptor so I cannot use Java libs/functions.

Comment: You tagged question as Java and cannot Java's most common String class methods?

Comment: I tagged it as Java because I imagine the regex needs to be Java compatible. I don't think unix shell or Perl regex syntax applies 1:1 to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String str = line.split(" ")[2].replaceAll("(.+)(\\[|\\:|\\/).+", "$1");
```

Haven't tested it.

Comment: I am passing regex in flume config to the regex interceptor so I cannot use Java libs/functions.

Answer (score 0):

The regex I think you're looking for is:

```
String regex = "([^\\[:/]+).*";
```

`.*` says to match 0 or more of any character. Putting a pair of parenthesis in front of the dot star `().*` creates a group that can be selected from a Matcher. Since it is the first set of parenthesis, it is referenced by group number 1. Inside the parenthesis is an expression that matches 1 or more of the negated character class `[^]+` containing the characters specified in the OP, specifically the "[", ":", and "/" characters.

Here is an example application testing the results:

```
package com.stackexchange.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Question19370191 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "([^\\[:/]+).*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd[6359]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd:3322 Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd/6359 Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname sshd Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname SSHD[1133] Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");
        lines.add("2013-10-14T22:05:29+00:00 hostname SSH.D[6359]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.10");

        for(String line : lines) {
            String field = line.split("\\s")[2];
            String extraction = "";
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);
            if(matcher.matches()) {
                extraction = matcher.group(1);
            }

            System.out.println(String.format("Field \"%-12s\" Extraction \"%s\"", field, extraction));
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
Field "sshd[6359]: " Extraction "sshd"
Field "sshd:3322   " Extraction "sshd"
Field "sshd/6359   " Extraction "sshd"
Field "sshd        " Extraction "sshd"
Field "SSHD[1133]  " Extraction "SSHD"
Field "SSH.D[6359]:" Extraction "SSH.D"
```

Comment: I am passing regex to another module as config so cannot use split.

Comment: Does this mean that each input line is actually coming from an InputStream rather than a List<String>?

Comment: I suppose so. The regex is passed to a flume agent as config to be used with the regex interceptor of flume.

Answer (score 0):

if your example data will be exactly like you have provided:

```
(?:.+?\s){2}([\w\.]+).+$
```

explained:

`(?:.+?\s){2}`...match up to the second space

`([^\s[:/]+)`...match anything that isn't a ' ', ':' or '/'

`.+$`...match to EOL

what you want will be in captured group `\1`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I take your regex and a sample log line and try it out here: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ - your regex matches the entire line.